# How do we define ample vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbf C$. How do we define an ample vector bundle $E$?

Do we just ask its determinant $\det $ to be ample?

Is it the same as saying that $f^\ast E$ is ample on $\mathbf P(E)$, where $f:\mathbf P(E)\to X$ is the projective bundle associated to $E$?

Answer (score 12):

1) The answer to your first question is that by definition the rank $r$ vector bundle $E$ on $X$ is ample if the line bundle $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)}(1)$ on $\mathbb P(E)$ is ample.
[ If  $ r=1$ we apparently have two definitions for the amplitude of the line bundle $E$, but they clearly coincide since $\mathbb P(E)=X$ and $O_{\mathbb P(E)}(1)=E$.]

2) An important property  is that a quotient bundle  of an ample bundle is ample.
This allows to negatively answer your second question, whether  a bundle whose determinant is ample is ample:
Take $X=\mathbb P^1$ and $E=\mathcal O(-1)\oplus \mathcal O(2)$.
 Then $\det(E)=\mathcal O(1)$, which is an ample line bundle.
Nevertheless  $E$ is not ample because one of its quotients is $\mathcal O(-1)$, which is certainly not ample.
[In the other direction it is true, however, that the determinant of an ample bundle is ample.]

3) Another important property is that the restriction $E|Y$ of an ample vector bundle on $X$  to any subvariety $Y\subset X$ is ample.
This immediately implies that for a vector bundle $E$ of rank $\gt 1$ the lifted bundle $f^*E$ on $\mathbb P(E)$ is never ample since its restriction to a fiber of $f$ is trivial, and thus certainly not ample.
This answers your third and last question, again negatively.

**Edit**
Although ample line bundles are an older concept, inextricably linked to the venerable notion of divisors, ample vector bundles of rank $\gt 1$ were introduced by Hartshorne only in 1966, in [this article](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Farchive.numdam.org%2Farticle%2FPMIHES_1966__29__63_0.pdf&ei=bzBrUfz4LOnL0QX26oGIAQ&usg=AFQjCNFskAcMS3JjCCtu4UZoybOUQGTP8w&bvm=bv.45175338,d.d2k).
He gives another definition of "ample", but the one I chose  (because it is  closer to the notions in Jim's question) is equivalent by Proposition 3.2  of the article.
By the way, ample vector bundles  of  rank $\gt 1$ are not mentioned in Hartshorne's  celebrated book and as an ironic consequence his generalized concept of "ample"  is not as well known as it deserves...

Comment: I thought that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is always ample? And can you give an EGA-reference for this theory?

Comment: @Martin, no $O_{\mathbb P(E)}(1)$ has no reason to be ample, as follows from my parenthetical remark at the end of 1) . There is no EGA-reference for ample vector bundles of rank $\gt1$ because they were defined only later by  Hartshorne . I have given a reference to his seminal paper in an Edit.